# R ggplot adding extra data points in plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm new to R, so maybe I'm overlooking something basic here. I'm having an issue where my box/whisker plot with jitter is duplicating certain data points.

First I'm creating two subsets of data as pulled from a database

```
postProgram<-subset(sData,sData$PROGRAM_STATUS=="POST-PROGRAM" & sData$CLASS_DESC=="Widget1" & MARKET_NAME!="N/A")
preProgram<-subset(sData,sData$PROGRAM_STATUS=="PRE-PROGRAM"& sData$CLASS_DESC=="Widget1" & MARKET_NAME!="N/A")
```

Next, I drop the extra levels left over by subset()

```
postProgram<-droplevels(postProgram)
preProgram<-droplevels(preProgram)
```

Now I just wanted to plot the preProgram values as a box-whisker so I aggregate all of the stores in each market as a single weekly total

```
preAgg<-setNames(aggregate(preProgram$DST_UNITS,by=list(preProgram$MARKET_NAME,preProgram$WEEK_DATE),"sum"),c("MARKET_NAME","WEEK_DATE","DST_UNITS"))
```

Finally, I go to plot it using ggplot

```
p<-ggplot(preAgg,aes(factor(MARKET_NAME),DST_UNITS))
p + geom_boxplot(aes(fill=factor(MARKET_NAME))) + geom_jitter(position=position_jitter(width=.2)) + xlab("Market Name") + ylab("Units Sold") +
  ggtitle("Pre-Program Weekly Units Sold By Region") + theme(legend.position="none")
```

And my issue is that for three of the markets I have 8 data points. That's impossible because there are only 7 weeks of data x 5 markets = 35 data points.

[image: ggplot]

What makes me more confused is that R Studio shows only 7 levels for the date information

[image: r studio]

Just for my own sanity I also checked the NYC / Long Island data with subset() and there are clearly only 7 data points. What is ggplot doing? This only affects 3 of the regions.

```
> subset(preAgg,preAgg$MARKET_NAME=='NYC / Long Island')
         MARKET_NAME  WEEK_DATE DST_UNITS
5  NYC / Long Island 2014-03-03        69
10 NYC / Long Island 2014-03-10        88
15 NYC / Long Island 2014-03-17        80
20 NYC / Long Island 2014-03-24        74
25 NYC / Long Island 2014-03-31        64
30 NYC / Long Island 2014-04-07        81
35 NYC / Long Island 2014-04-14       179
```

Comment: some of the points are probably 'outlier' points (i.e. beyond 1.5 the fence, or whatever the criterion is) added by `geom_boxplot`.  The clue is that they're lined up vertically the whiskers and (approximately) horizontally with a jittered point (markets 2, 3, and 5, I think)

Comment: Ugh you are correct. I just tried adding outlier.shape=NA and that resolved the issue. I didn't even think about it after scratching my head with this. Thanks! Simple solution.

Comment: You can post this as an answer if you like ...

Comment: How do I post a comment as an answer? Quote it in the "Answer your Question"?

Comment: Yes -- just write an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Answer by Ben Bolker in comments. Plot was showing outliers in addition to data points.